# IR receiver receives only 0

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, ir, remote-control

I am trying to decode IR codes of my Samsung tv remote
But the receiver always receiving "0"
Schematics:

[image: Schematics]

Code:

```
#include <IRremote.h>      

int RECV_PIN = 11;        
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;
 
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn();
}
 
void loop() 
{
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) 
    {
    int value = results.value;
    Serial.println(" ");
    Serial.print("Code: ");
    Serial.println(results.value); 
    Serial.println(" ");
    irrecv.resume();              
    Serial.println("*****************");
    }
}
```

Please help me to decode my IR codes

Comment: The most current version of IRremote doesn't have any arguments for the `decode` function. To get the result you'd use `irrecv.results` to get the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next update with [3.1 of the library](https://github.com/Arduino-IRremote/Arduino-IRremote#converting-your-2x-program-to-the-3x-version), you need to call `irrecv.decodedIRData.decodedRawData` to get the data. This code worked for me:

```
#include <IRremote.h>

int IRpin = 11;
IRrecv irrecv(IRpin);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
}

void loop() 
{
  if (irrecv.decode()) 
    {
      Serial.println(irrecv.decodedIRData.decodedRawData); // Print the Serial
      irrecv.resume();   // Receive the next value
    }
}
```